# React history.push() not rendering new component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a React.js project with a simple sign in function. After the user is authorized, I call history.push method which changes the link in the address bar but does not render the new component. (I use BrowserRouter)

My **index.js** component:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(mainReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Main />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My **Main.js** component:

```
const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Signin} />
      <Route exact path="/servers" component={Servers} />
    </Switch>
)}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

My **Action Creator**:

```
export const authorization = (username, password) => (dispatch) =>
  new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
    }).then( response => {
      if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then( result => {
            console.log("API reached.");
            dispatch(logUserIn(result.token));
            resolve(result);
        })
      } else {
        let error = new Error(response.statusText)
        error.response = response
        dispatch(showError(error.response.statusText), () => {throw error})
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

My **Signin.js** component:

```
 handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isLoading: true })

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.onLoginRequest(username, password, this.props.history).then(result => {
      console.log("Success. Token: "+result.token); //I do get "success" in console
      this.props.history.push('/servers') //Changes address, does not render /servers component
    });

  }

const mapActionsToProps = {
  onLoginRequest: authorization
}
```

The weirdest thing is that if I change my handleSubmit() method to this - everything works perfectly:

```
  handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isLoading: true })

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.onLoginRequest(username, password, this.props.history).then(result => {
      console.log("Success. Token: "+result.token);
      //this.props.history.push('/servers')
    });
    this.props.history.push('/servers')
  }
```

The same issue comes if I try to push history from the `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` method - it changes address but does not render new component. Could someone please explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Is your Signin component connected to Redux via connect()?

Comment: Silly question, I looked again and you are using action creators there so must be connected. Then, next question is do you use withRouter also or not?

Comment: @devserkan I currently use it on main.js (as you can see in the export). I've also tried it on Signin.js and Servers.js components - no luck.

Comment: Let's try using custom history and Router. I don't know it solves the issue for you but I am going to provide an answer.

Comment: did this problem solved ..? i'm having same problem not working with any of the approach

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If anyone is interested - this was happening because the app was rendering before the history was pushed. When I put the history push into my action but just before the result is converted into JSON, it started working since now it pushes history and only then renders the App.

```
export const authorization = (username, password, history) => (dispatch) =>
  new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
    }).then( response => {
      if (response.ok) {

          //################################
          //This is where I put it

          history.push("/servers");

          //################################

          response.json().then( result => {
            dispatch(logUserIn(result.token));
            resolve(result);
        })
      } else {
        let error = new Error(response.statusText)
        error.response = response
        dispatch(showError(error.response.statusText), () => {throw error})
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to apply withRouter to use this.props.history.push('/page') in every component that use "push"

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
.....
export default
        withRouter(MoneyExchange);
```

this is important when using push.

Comment: if you do have another higher order component like i did (aws withAuthenticator) you can just wrap one around another and it will work just fine also. Something like this: export default withRouter(withAuthenticator(ListNotesPage));

Answer (score 5):

First, create a history object used the history package:

```
// src/history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Then wrap it in  in Main Router Component.

```
    import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import history from './history';

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Fragment>
              <Header />
              <Switch>
                <SecureRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route exact path={LOGIN_PAGE} component={LoginPage} />
                <Route exact path={ERROR_PAGE} component={ErrorPage} />
              </Switch>
              <Footer />
            </Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Provider>)
```

Here, After dispatching the request, redirecting to home page.

```
    function requestItemProcess(value) {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(request(value));
            history.push('/');
        };

    }
```

should be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use custom history and Router instead of BrowserRouter. After installing history:

```
yarn add history
```

Create a custom browser history:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Use Router instead of BrowserRouter in your setup:

```
import history from "your_history_file";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(mainReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Main />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

or if you don't want to use a custom history file and import from there you can crate it directly in your index.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(mainReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Main />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, same issue with this code as well. :(

Comment: Weird, I solved a similar problem with this way. React+Redux and history.push. But, your problem could be different since outside of then block it is working for you. I hope you find a solution. One last thing, if possible drop withRouter from your Main app then try again with my suggestion.

Comment: Still does not work. I believe this issue is more related to the asynchronicity of my request.

Answer (score 1):

I using react-electron-boilerplate and i experienced a issue using `MemoryRouter`

using `history.push('/someUrl')` doesn't work...

Just use `exact` property in  component, and `initialEntries` to set your default route.

```html
    <Router initialEntries={['/']}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Route exact path="/session" component={SessionScreen} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not Working on this one* ->

```
handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isLoading: true })

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.onLoginRequest(username, password, this.props.history).then(result => {
      console.log("Success. Token: "+result.token); //I do get "success" in console
      this.props.history.push('/servers') //Changes address, does not render /servers component
    });

  }

const mapActionsToProps = {
  onLoginRequest: authorization
}
```

Because in this `handleSubmit` method you are calling `this.props.history.push()` inside a promise so the  `this` is pointing to the Promise's instance not your current class instance.

Try this One ->

```
 handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    const { history: { push } } = this.props;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.onLoginRequest(username, password, this.props.history).then(result => {
      console.log("Success. Token: "+result.token); //I do get "success" in console
      push('/servers') //Changes address, does not render /servers component
    });
  }

const mapActionsToProps = {
  onLoginRequest: authorization
}
```

Now In this Statement ->

```
 handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isLoading: true })

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.onLoginRequest(username, password, this.props.history).then(result => {
      console.log("Success. Token: "+result.token);
      //this.props.history.push('/servers')
    });
    this.props.history.push('/servers')
  }
```

You are correctly calling this.props.history.push() since it is out of the promise and referring to the Current Class instance.

Comment: It then says: "push is not defined". I've also tried like this:
this.props.onLoginRequest(username, password).then(result => {
      console.log("Success. Token: "+result.token);
      this.props.history.push('/servers')
    }); - didn't work either.

Comment: Did you added this line - > `const { history: { push } } = this.props;`

Comment: Ugh, sorry, missed that part. Added. Now push works, but the same issue persists - address changed, success logged, servers component still does not render.
And if this issue is related to promise - why does history.push not work with componentWillReceiveProps where I receive prop called loggedIn and then the push() is activated, but the exact same issue persists - new component not rendered.

Comment: This is a bad example to follow. It removes `this.props.history.push('/servers')` from asynchronous execution in the promise. That line will not fire regardless of whether `onLoginRequest` successfully completes. Similarly, it may execute before that promise above even resolves assuming it is making a network call.